# Does it make any sense to install anti-virus on Windows XP Mode?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, windows-xp-mode

This is almost certainly a dumb question, but... say I have Windows 7, with some anti-virus software installed, and I am using Microsoft's [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) to run some legacy applications  as well. Is there any reason why I would want to install an anti-virus program in XP mode as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a dumb question at all.

XP Mode is another virtualized environment. If you will be utilizing applications inside it that are accessing the internet, it would be a smart idea to protect it. Your anti-virus on the Windows 7 host can only do so much, you'll need to install separate protection in XP Mode if you want the additional security. I'd recommend doing so.

Comment: I agree, first thing I did after setting up the XP mode was to patch it all and install Microsoft Security Essentials on it.